# Jupyter Notebook Q# kernal not connecting

Tags: jupyter-notebook, q#

I recently updated iqsharp(from 0.10 to 0.11) for jupyter notebooks (via Anaconda) and ever since, the Q# kernel stopped connecting when I open a new or existing Q# notebook. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling jupyter notebook as well as iqsharp but nothing seems to have changed.

I had initially installed iqsharp for Jupyter Notebook following the instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/quantum/install-guide/qjupyter) and updated it to the latest version using the instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/quantum/install-guide/update#update-iq-for-jupyter-notebooks).

I think it may have something to do with, `"Access to the path 'C:\Users\neera\Application Data' is denied"` appearing in the terminal though I am not quite sure what it means.

```
iqsharp: 0.11.2004.2825
Jupyter Core: 1.3.52077.0
.NET Runtime: .NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: When specifically are you seeing that error message? Is this in the Jupyter console output, or is it the output of some command that you are running? If you could include more of the context around the error message, it would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Update:]

As discussed in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/microsoft/iqsharp/issues/149), this seems to be related to your Q# `.ipynb` notebook file living in your `Users` folder, alongside the `Application Data` folder which for some reason is inaccessible.

You should be able to workaround this issue by creating/opening your Q# `.ipynb` notebook files from any other folder on your disk.

Thanks for providing the additional information!

---

[Old answer:]

It sounds like some type of installation problem. (I've left a comment asking for more details to help diagnose more specifically.) But in general, what you could try is to completely uninstall and reinstall the iqsharp tool by doing the following:

```
dotnet tool uninstall -g Microsoft.Quantum.IQSharp
dotnet tool install -g Microsoft.Quantum.IQSharp
dotnet iqsharp install
```